# Inserting in db is extremely slow - SSIS OLE DB Destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have been experienced that my DB is experiencing a lot of performance issues and after some time I have observer that an SSIS jobs takes extremely long time to inserting new rows through SSIS OLE DB Destination .
I have checked the following things so far:
Data access mode : Table or view fast mode with marked: "Table lock" and "Check constraints", "Row per batch" is empty and Maximum insert commit : 2147483647
Number of rows for inserting have been a really small number <100 so I dont really understand that it takes 20-30 minutes for this. I think its the insert which is slow because all previous data tasks are marked green check so I believe its correct.
Have read that this could be because of the index in the tabel but how this can be checked to confirm or exclude?

Comment: Please add tags to your post regarding which database system you're using (in assuming Microsoft SQL Server) and which version.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2019, I will add tags

Comment: Do you observer blocking during the insert?

Comment: @DanGuzman, The select queies I strongly believe are being blocked as I have experienced by my self that the select queries  are just executing for long time without any data to be displayed which normally takes 5 sec. 
I do not know whether inserting are being blocked if select queries are running at same time, can that happen?

Comment: @gk1993_aal, SELECT queries can block inserts and visa-versa. You can execute `sp_who` to identify blocking/blocked sessions or other methods, such as in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205528/dba-blocking-query-email-alert). Maybe you should schedule the package to run during periods of low activity.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to change it so that Insert has higher priority then Select so that Insert are not blocked ?

Comment: Has the target table an ID column with a SEQUENCE as default? If yes, check the cache property of the SEQUENCE object (I once had the case, that the SELECT of a few million rows took maybe 2 minutes, but the INSERT 40 minutes, until I found, that the sequence had a cache value of only 20...)

Comment: Are you running the SSIS on the server? If you are loading a CSV via SSIS and have the CSV file on your laptop, while you are connected through a slow VPN connection to your companies LAN, it has to move the data from / to your laptop (if you are running SSIS local)

Comment: BTW: what happens if you are inserting into a new, empty table (with or without indexes / IDs / default columns etc.)? Faster / slower / same? This may help to find the reason / culprint.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change it so that Insert has higher priority then Select so that Insert are not blocked

If you enable the database option [READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) then the SELECT will not require locks or block the INSERT.  Also you could run the SELECT under SNAPSHOT transaction isolation level.

Comment: Thank you David
Can you tell how can I confirm that there is no issue with the index so that I am sure before I change theses settings?

Comment: The best starting point for understanding the performance of your workload is Query Store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @gk1993_aal you could test this by creating a copy of the table in a different database and experimenting with it.